# Why do my calls to gpiod_set_value return an "invalid GPIO" error?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, gpio

I am attempting to write a driver for an OV2680 camera sensor. I want to turn on some GPIO pins as one of the steps in its `->probe()` function. Those GpioIo() pins are declared in the DSDT tables like so (for a device upon which the OV2680 is dependent; see [full DSDT table](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/djrscally/e64d112180517352fa3392878b0f4a7d/raw/88b90b3ea4204fd7845257b6666fdade47cc2981/dsdt.dsl):

```asl
        Device (PMI1)
        {
            Name (_ADR, Zero)  // _ADR: Address
            Name (_HID, "INT3472")  // _HID: Hardware ID
            Name (_CID, "INT3472")  // _CID: Compatible ID
            Name (_DDN, "INCL-CRDD")  // _DDN: DOS Device Name
            Name (_UID, One)  // _UID: Unique ID
            Method (_CRS, 0, NotSerialized)  // _CRS: Current Resource Settings
            {
                Name (SBUF, ResourceTemplate ()
                {
                    GpioIo (Exclusive, PullDefault, 0x0000, 0x0000, IoRestrictionOutputOnly,
                        "\\_SB.PCI0.GPI0", 0x00, ResourceConsumer, ,
                        )
                        {   // Pin list
                            0x0079
                        }
                    GpioIo (Exclusive, PullDefault, 0x0000, 0x0000, IoRestrictionOutputOnly,
                        "\\_SB.PCI0.GPI0", 0x00, ResourceConsumer, ,
                        )
                        {   // Pin list
                            0x007A
                        }
                    GpioIo (Exclusive, PullDefault, 0x0000, 0x0000, IoRestrictionOutputOnly,
                        "\\_SB.PCI0.GPI0", 0x00, ResourceConsumer, ,
                        )
                        {   // Pin list
                            0x008F
                        }
                })
                Return (SBUF) /* \_SB_.PCI0.PMI1._CRS.SBUF */
            }
        }

        Device (CAM1)
        {
            Name (_ADR, Zero)  // _ADR: Address
            Name (_HID, "OVTI2680")  // _HID: Hardware ID
            Name (_CID, "OVTI2680")  // _CID: Compatible ID
            Name (_DDN, "OV2680-CRDD")  // _DDN: DOS Device Name
            Name (_UID, One)  // _UID: Unique ID
            Name (_DEP, Package (0x02)  // _DEP: Dependencies
            {
                PMI1, 
                I2C2
            })
            Name (_PLD, Package (0x01)  // _PLD: Physical Location of Device
            {
                ToPLD (
                    PLD_Revision           = 0x2,
                    PLD_IgnoreColor        = 0x1,
                    PLD_Red                = 0x0,
                    PLD_Green              = 0x0,
                    PLD_Blue               = 0x0,
                    PLD_Width              = 0x0,
                    PLD_Height             = 0x0,
                    PLD_UserVisible        = 0x1,
                    PLD_Dock               = 0x0,
                    PLD_Lid                = 0x0,
                    PLD_Panel              = "FRONT",
                    PLD_VerticalPosition   = "CENTER",
                    PLD_HorizontalPosition = "RIGHT",
                    PLD_Shape              = "VERTICALRECTANGLE",
                    PLD_GroupOrientation   = 0x0,
                    PLD_GroupToken         = 0x0,
                    PLD_GroupPosition      = 0x0,
                    PLD_Bay                = 0x0,
                    PLD_Ejectable          = 0x1,
                    PLD_EjectRequired      = 0x1,
                    PLD_CabinetNumber      = 0x0,
                    PLD_CardCageNumber     = 0x0,
                    PLD_Reference          = 0x0,
                    PLD_Rotation           = 0x0,
                    PLD_Order              = 0x0,
                    PLD_VerticalOffset     = 0xFFFF,
                    PLD_HorizontalOffset   = 0xFFFF)

            })
            Method (_CRS, 0, NotSerialized)  // _CRS: Current Resource Settings
            {
                Name (SBUF, ResourceTemplate ()
                {
                    I2cSerialBusV2 (0x0010, ControllerInitiated, 0x00061A80,
                        AddressingMode7Bit, "\\_SB.PCI0.I2C2",
                        0x00, ResourceConsumer, , Exclusive,
                        )
                })
                Return (SBUF) /* \_SB_.PCI0.CAM1._CRS.SBUF */
            }
        }
```

Note absence of a _DSD segment, meaning I have to explicitly declare them in the driver code [according to the documentation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/firmware-guide/acpi/gpio-properties.rst#acpi-gpio-mappings-provided-by-drivers). That's no problem; I have the `struct acpi_device` for this ACPI device (by scraping the dependents of the OV2680 device that the driver matches to), so I can do that and add them with `acpi_dev_add_driver_gpios()` as the documentation instructs. My question comes in the [Getting GPIO Descriptor](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/firmware-guide/acpi/gpio-properties.rst#getting-gpio-descriptor) stage; the documentation says to use `gpiod_get_index()`, which function calls for a `struct device` rather than a `struct acpi_device`. I've tried to fulfill this by passing the `struct acpi_device::dev` member, but although I don't receive any error messages upon doing so, nothing actually seems to happen when I set the GPIO pins live, so I don't think that it's working.

Given this is hardware specific I'm not sure a MRE is useful, but here's a driver that should compile and be inserted successfully:

```c
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/i2c.h>
#include <linux/acpi.h>
#include <linux/gpio/consumer.h>
#include <linux/platform_device.h>

static const struct acpi_gpio_params gpio1 = {0, 0, false};
static const struct acpi_gpio_params gpio2 = {1, 0, false};
static const struct acpi_gpio_params gpio3 = {2, 0, false};

static const struct acpi_gpio_mapping int3472_acpi_gpios[] = {
    {"gpio1", &gpio1, 1},
    {"gpio2", &gpio2, 1},
    {"gpio3", &gpio3, 1},
    {}
};

static int ov2680_probe(struct i2c_client *client)
{    
    /*
     * The driver will match the OV2680 device, but the GPIO
     * pins lie in its dependent INT3472, so we need to walk
     * up the dependencies to find that device.
    */
   struct acpi_device *int3472_device;

   /* get ACPI handle of OV2680 device */
   struct acpi_handle *dev_handle = ACPI_HANDLE(&client->dev);

   /* Get dependent devices */
   struct acpi_handle_list dep_devices;
   acpi_evaluate_reference(dev_handle, "_DEP", NULL, &dep_devices);

   int i;
   for (i=0; i < dep_devices.count; i++) {
       struct acpi_device_info *devinfo;
       acpi_get_object_info(dep_devices.handles[i], &devinfo);

       if (devinfo->valid & ACPI_VALID_HID && !strcmp(devinfo->hardware_id.string, "INT3472")) {
           acpi_bus_get_device(dep_devices.handles[i], &int3472_device);
       }
   }

   int ret;

   ret = acpi_dev_add_driver_gpios(int3472_device, int3472_acpi_gpios);

   struct gpio_desc *gpiod1, *gpiod2, *gpiod3;

   gpiod1 = gpiod_get_index(&int3472_device->dev, NULL, 0, GPIOD_ASIS);
   gpiod2 = gpiod_get_index(&int3472_device->dev, NULL, 1, GPIOD_ASIS);
   gpiod3 = gpiod_get_index(&int3472_device->dev, NULL, 2, GPIOD_ASIS);
   
   gpiod_set_value_cansleep(gpiod1, 1);
   gpiod_set_value_cansleep(gpiod2, 1);
   gpiod_set_value_cansleep(gpiod3, 1);

   return 0;
}

static int ov2680_remove(struct i2c_client *client)
{
    /*
     * Code goes here to get acpi_device, turn off all
     * the GPIO pins, remove them from the ACPI device
     * and whatnot
     */

    return 0;
}

static const struct acpi_device_id ov2680_acpi_match[] = {
    {"OVTI2680", 0},
    { }
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(acpi, ov2680_acpi_match);

static struct i2c_driver ov2680_driver = {
    .driver = {
        .name = "ov2680",
        .acpi_match_table = ov2680_acpi_match,
    },
    .probe_new = ov2680_probe,
    .remove = ov2680_remove,
};
module_i2c_driver(ov2680_driver);

MODULE_AUTHOR("Dan Scally");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A driver for OmniVision 2680 sensors");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

`dmesg` reports no problems in adding the pins or anything, but the calls to `gpiod_set_value_cansleep()` throw an error there:

> [4840.774633] gpiod_set_value_cansleep: invalid GPIO (errorpointer)

This transpires to be because the calls to `gpiod_get_index()` have failed, and thus the GPIO descriptors are invalid.

Questions:

1. Is my use of `&int3472->device` as a parameter to `gpiod_get_index()` the correct approach?
2. If so, what might cause the calls to `gpiod_get_index()` to fail?

EDITS:

Output of `grep -H 15 /sys/bus/acpi/devices/*/status`

```
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/ACPI000C:00/status:15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/BOSC0200:00/status:15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:16/status:15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:17/status:15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:32/status:15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT33D3:00/status:15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT33D6:00/status:15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3400:00/status:15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT340E:00/status:15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT344B:00/status:15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3472:08/status:15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3472:09/status:15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3F0D:00/status:15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/MSFT0001:00/status:15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/MSFT0101:00/status:15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/OVTI2680:00/status:15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/OVTI5648:00/status:15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0103:00/status:15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0401:01/status:15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0A05:04/status:15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C09:00/status:15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0C:00/status:15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0D:00/status:15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/VPC2004:00/status:15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/WCOM508C:00/status:15
```

Comment: In this case, the calls to `gpiod_set_value_cansleep()` are failing because the calls to `gpiod_get_index()` are returning an `ERR_PTR()` value. So the problem lies with the calls to `gpiod_get_index()`, not with the calls to `gpiod_set_value_cansleep()`.

Comment: @IanAbbot yeeeeeeaaaaas looks like the `gpio_descs` that returns aren't valid. Turns out I didn't have the GPIO Drivers loaded which might be why, so just rebuilding the kernel with those to see what, if any, different that makes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Gathering the answer based on comments I have given earlier)

For sake of the clarification I have to say, that from your DSDT we can get the following information. There are 3 groups of PMICs, i.e. `DSCx`, `CLPx` and `PMIx`. I believe they are based on the model, like *Desktop*, *Laptop*, *2-in-1*. And in each case all PMICs in the same group have different `_UID`. From the provided output of the `grep -H 15 ...` we have only 2 out of 10 enumerated with the instances **INT3472:08** and **INT3472:09** (exactly two last defined in DSDT). And they are `PMIx`, you may check this by `grep -H . /sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3472:*/path`.

Your interest is the `PMI1` which **consumes** three GPIO lines from [Intel GPIO driver](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/pinctrl/intel/pinctrl-sunrisepoint.c#L61), i.e. pins 121, 122 and 143 (you may decode them as Community #2, Group #5 or GPP_F, relative to the group pins 1, 2 and 23, this may help you to understand `_INI` method that touches these lines via other methods in DSDT), and **provides** 3 + 7 = 10 pins according to [its driver](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/gpio/gpio-tps68470.c#L119).

Now to the code. The `_DEP` ACPI method is used solely for linking power resources, and Linux kernel has other means how to hijack resources from other device, because what you are trying to do is to use the resource which is not related to the device you are creating driver for.

The method is to find device by ACPI HID:

```c
struct acpi_device *adev;
struct device *phys_dev;
struct gpio_desc *desc;

...

adev = acpi_dev_get_first_match_dev("INT3472", "1", -1);
if (!adev) {
  pr_err("Oops, we didn't find an ACPI device!\n");
  return -ENODEV;
}

phys_dev = get_device(acpi_get_first_physical_node(adev));
acpi_dev_put(adev);

if (!phys_dev) {
  pr_err("Oops, we didn't find a physical device!\n");
  return -ENODEV;
}

desc = gpiod_get_index(phys_dev, NULL, 0, GPIOD_ASIS);
if (IS_ERR(desc)) {
  pr_err("Something went wrong when retrieving GPIO\n");
  put_device(phys_dev);
  return PTR_ERR(desc);
}

...

gpiod_put(desc);
put_device(phys_dev);
```

Hackish way to simplify this (since you know bus type and exact name of the device instance, but Linux does not guarantee it is kept the same over boots) is:

```c
struct device *phys_dev;
struct gpio_desc *desc;

...

phys_dev = bus_find_device_by_name(&i2c_bus_type, NULL, "i2c-INT3472:09");
if (!phys_dev) {
  pr_err("Oops, we didn't find a physical device!\n");
  return -ENODEV;
}

desc = gpiod_get_index(phys_dev, NULL, 0, GPIOD_ASIS);
if (IS_ERR(desc)) {
  pr_err("Something went wrong when retrieving GPIO\n");
  put_device(phys_dev);
  return PTR_ERR(desc);
}

...

gpiod_put(desc);
put_device(phys_dev);
```

Side notes:

1. There is already [existing driver](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/media/i2c/ov2680.c) for OV2680 camera sensor, it makes sense to extend it instead of creating a specific fork for ACPI case.
2. The proper method is to use resources where they can be consumed without any hacks, i.e. in the PMIC [MFD driver](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/mfd/tps68470.c#L54).

Comment: hi, @0andriy, this post is very useful.gpiod_get_index should call on phy_dev and get the resource, but how can I call on adev->dev? like gpiod_get_index(&adev->dev, ....)?

Comment: @PoplarGiant It depends on what is the device you get `struct acpi_device` for. If ACPI device is a companion, the `acpi_get_first_physical_node()` should help. So without seeing ASL it’s hard to give a proper answer.

Comment: I registered a driver in modue_init by using `acpi_bus_register_driver(&pmic_driver)`, and get the acpi_device adev in `pmic_driver_add(struct acpi_device* adev)`. 

And I managed to get gpio resources with code similar with implementation of acpi_get_first_physical_node, but I can't invoke un-exported acpi_get_first_physical_node in driver/media/i2c/xxx.I currently copy codes of acpi_get_first_physical_node, which seems hacky. I want to avoid hacky code.

Comment: I found that adev has null fwnode, phsy_dev has non-null fwnode. fwnode seems necessary for getting gpio resources.I'm guessing I missed some necessary bindings between the adev I get from `pmic_driver_add()` and the actual phsy_dev node.
Could you please share any ideas on this?

Comment: @PoplarGiant You are using pure ACPI driver model, which shouldn’t be used. Switch your PMIC driver to be a *platform driver*. WRT exported function, it seems I was thinking about something else. I need to think about it.